# How can a PreferenceActivity use a custom preference file

Tags: android, android-preferences

My first attempt at preferences was without knowledge of `PreferenceActivity`. So now I have an app that stores all user preferences in a specific preference file.

I want to migrate to using a PreferenceActivity but I also want my users to keep their preferences.

Is there a way to tell my PreferenceActivity to use that specific file for all preferences?

Comment: You could write a method that reads your old preferences and saves them as regular preferences

Comment: I thought about migration as one solution. But then I can never get rid of the migration code? There is no way to ensure that there are no old versions of my app around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read all the preferences at the beginning of your app, and then store them in the `Preferences` using

```
Editor e = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext()).edit();
e.putBoolean("yourPreference", true);
e.putString("yourOtherPreference", "This is the Value");
...
e.commit();
```

I hope that helps

Comment: I implemented this variant now even though I initially preferred the renaming of the file idea of Andrew. I never found out how to do the latter however and so I stuck with the obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 68):

It may be too late to post this but you can find a nice solution here

- [How to make PreferenceActivity use non-default SharedPreferences](http://idlesun.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-make-preferenceactivity-use-non.html)

You set the name of the default shared preferences file beforehand like this:

```
public class MyPreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         PreferenceManager prefMgr = getPreferenceManager();
         prefMgr.setSharedPreferencesName("my_preferences");
         prefMgr.setSharedPreferencesMode(MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

         addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps somebody.

Regards.

Comment: Nice answer (although deprecated ... ) Edited because link was broken - and copied the code from the link. Although IMHO it is a mistake to use `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

Maaalte is correct, what you want to do is onCreate test for the existence of your custom file and if it's there, rename it to standard shared preferences filename.

Another option is to read your old prefs one-by-one and use the shared preferences API to add them as you read them and then delete your old prefs when you are done.