# Can Android Preferences/Settings screen be configured to use preferences other than 'DEFAULT' shared preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, settings, android-preferences

Android Tutorials and examples show how to use **Preference Fragment and Preference Activity** to create **Settings screen** in an app.

However, all preferences exposed this way get their values to '**DefaultSharedPreferences**'.

What if we want to save preference values to other (non-default / custom) SharedPreferences.

The use case I have in mind is similar to email apps where an app may allow the user to create multiple accounts, and also give the user options to save settings for different accounts differently. One method that I see as an option would have been to 'programatially' add preference in the Preference screens, and specify a different Shared Preference target for each one of them (depending on account).

However, it seems that currently all preferences added to PreferenceFragment/Activity get their values saved to DefaultSharedPreferences.

Any pointers on this will be appreciated.

One

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a PreferenceActivity use a custom preference file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5169532/how-can-a-preferenceactivity-use-a-custom-preference-file)

Answer (score 1):

Technically these three lines will get the job done from one side. And now that it sets the Preference for all the activities, the simple way to overcome that is it initialize default SharedPreferences where needed and Custom SharedPreferences where are wanted.

```
getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("custom_prefs");
getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesMode(MODE_PRIVATE);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this really helps - a follow up question -- your example gives us a way to configure the preference file name for the whole Settings Activity. Is it possible to set it for a category of preferences, or individual preferences?

Comment: I have edited the answer. This one will help you out.