# Can we use Shared Preferences in an multiple Activities

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

It may seem as beginner question....I am trying to use 2 pref 1 from Registartion_Activity and other from Some_Other_Activity....Is it possible

Comment: Shared preferences should be  used as global .

Comment: Any [minimal, complete and verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Comment: Using multiple shared pref file is permissible but instead of that I would suggest to use default shared pref file and use different keys to store data.

Comment: Yes it possible. You need to declare it in the Activities. Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759369/can-android-preferences-settings-screen-be-configured-to-use-preferences-other-t/36797502#36797502 
Although I would suggest using the same Default Sharedpreferences.

Comment: Thank you for your help........This problem evoked because of another problem.......I was 'trying to use Shared Preferences in ContentProvider'..........It seems that it is not possible.......But at the end I want to send an id from My_Activity to Content Provider for that I was Using SharedP......Any other alternative

Answer (score 0):

Sure, Why not.

Use [`context.getSharedPreferences()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) With some name and use the same name from multiple `Activities` or make it different if you want to separate them.

**OR**

Use [`getDefaultSharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29) from multiple `Activities` and write in default if you want to use in common.